# find given subnet is overlapping in Active Directory subnet

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, active-directory, subnet

i am looking for vb / power shell script. i need to check given subnet is overlapping with AD subnet or not.  For eg. if i gave input as 192.168.2.0/24 subnet the script need to check this subnet is already mapped to some other AD site or overlapping with other subnet.  If any one pls help on this.

Regards,

Karthick V

Comment: What do you mean by "mapped to" AD?

Comment: We're here to help, but there appears to be little to no research done on this issue up front and/or there's very little for someone here to go on to assist you.  It is recommended that you post things you've already tried or options you are considering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is close, as it will take IP addresses, but it won't take subnets.

```
nltest /DSADDRESSTOSITE: /ADDRESSES:192.168.1.64
```

If the given IP address is part of a site and subnet pair that is defined in Active Directory, the output will resemble:

```
Get the site-subnet mapping from '\\DC01.contoso.com'.
  192.168.1.64  Paris  192.168.1.0/24
```

If the IP address was not part of a site-subnet mapping in Active Directory, the output will resemble:

```
Get the site-subnet mapping from '\\DC01.contoso.com'.
  192.168.1.64  Default-First-Site-Name (null)
```

So in your script, you'd probably be looking for `(null)` to verify that the given IP address was *not* part of an AD site.

If you wanted to check a whole bunch of IPs at once,

```
nltest /DSADDRESSTOSITE: /ADDRESSES:$( (Get-Content C:\Temp\IPs.txt ) -join ",")
```

You could write a script that's a little snazzier than that, but I'm too lazy to write the whole thing for you right now.

By the way, it's OK to have overlapping subnets defined in Active Directory. The domain member will simply choose the smallest/most specific subnet to which it belongs.